# Excel VBA button and controls change size on different computers

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a VBA interface running inside an Excel spreadsheet. It is a thing that many of us share. On my own system, and on about 85% - 90% of the systems in our group, the controls all display well:

[image]

But on 15% - 20% of the systems, the button width looks like it changes, resulting in usable-but-ugly content:

[image]

Is this a system setting I have made incorrectly?

Addendum 1: I am running version 1712 (Build 8827.2179). The computer kicking out the wonky version is running 1902 (Build 11328.20420)

Addendum 2: It does not appear to be associated with Excel's zoom control, nor screen resolution settings. No matter how each of us monkey with those settings, his glitch remains and my form still looks good.

-=-=-=-=-

*Edit July 20, 2021: We were never able to figure out exactly how to solve this issue, nor replicate it in a way that allowed us to better troubleshoot. I was about to switch to using image/chiclets instead of buttons, but ultimately, during a UI overhaul, we switched from buttons to drop-down menus instead. I guess sometimes the best solution is to make it so that the problem doesn't matter? Sorry I didn't find a brilliant answer.*

Comment: Have you checked to see if the fonts used are also on the computers where things look wrong?

Comment: "Have you checked to see if the fonts used are also on the computers where things look wrong?" That is a good question. I used Tahoma and Tahoma is on the other computers.

Comment: @EdwardMartinIII Can you please include what version of Excel you're running? And what version are the other systems running?

Comment: "...what Excel version you are running..." I think I am running version 1712 (Build 8827.2179). I am waiting to hear back what version my test case has. We are SUPPOSED to be running the same version everywhere.

Comment: Re-looking at it, I notice on screencap is wider than the other. Are you both viewing the worksheet (I assume these buttons are on a worksheet) at the same zoom percentage?

Comment: The buttons are NOT on the worksheet -- they are on a form. On my system, no matter how much I zoom or unzoom, the form remains the same size. I am asking my guy if he'll check his zoom controls.

Comment: What about screen resolution?

Comment: I heard back from my guy -- no matter how he changes the Excel zoom control or the screen resolution, he seems to have the same issue when the form resolves. Moreover, no matter how much I change my zoom control or screen resolutions, I cannot duplicate his form glitch on my computer. Vexing. Good suggestions, though!

Comment: DId you check .Autosize option, .Locked option or .Wordwrap option?

Comment: You mentioned resolution settings and Excel's zoom control but I don't see where you're ruled out Windows zoom control or the font size controls in Ease of Access settings. 
These will change form and font size without changing screen resolution.  Definitely a suspect with your symptoms.

Comment: What about  setting "optimize for compatibility" in Excel General Options available in newer Office builds? - @EdwardMartinIII

Comment: This does not answer the question. However I had the same problem and was searching how to solve it. In my PC: A1.Left - B1.Left equals 48. In other computers it may be different, so what I did is multiply all widths and horizontal positions by 48/(A1.Left - B1.Left) in VBA. Similar with the vertical axis. Hope it helps